# How to troubleshoot python-selenium error “connection refused” when initializing a selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, firefox, web-scraping, geckodriver

I am trying to scrape a web site using Selenium, gecko driver and firefox. If I execute the script as root or as an ordinary user, it is working fine. But when I run it as apache (which is how it will be running in production), it is failing. Versions -
Mozilla Firefox 72.0
geckodriver 0.26.0
I have set log level to trace. Entries appearing in geckolog

```
1579004036460 mozrunner::runner INFO  Running command: "/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--disable-extensions" "--disable-infobars" "--disable-images" "--headless" "--disable-gpu" "--no-sandbox" "--disable-setuid-sandbox" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileKkQRyT"
1579004036461 geckodriver::marionette DEBUG Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:37317
*** You are running in headless mode.

(firefox:21013): dconf-CRITICAL **: 12:14:56.520: unable to create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(firefox:21013): dconf-CRITICAL **: 12:14:56.521: unable to create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(firefox:21013): dconf-CRITICAL **: 12:14:56.521: unable to create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(firefox:21013): dconf-CRITICAL **: 12:14:56.521: unable to create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(firefox:21013): dconf-CRITICAL **: 12:14:56.524: unable to create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
1579004096533 mozrunner::runner DEBUG Killing process 21013
1579004096537 webdriver::server DEBUG <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"timeout","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
```

In the session where I am executing the script, this is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/***.py", line 36, in <module>
    scrap_price()
  File "/var/www/html/***.py", line 26, in scrap_price
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko, options=options,firefox_profile=firefoxProfile, service_log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused
```

Relevant sections of the code

```
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
        options.add_argument('--disable-images')
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
        options.log.level = 'trace'
        gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver'))
        binary = FirefoxBinary('/bin/firefox')
        firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
        firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
        firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so','false')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=gecko, options=options,firefox_profile=firefoxPro
file, service_log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log')
        driver.get(urlpage)
```

OS is CentOS Linux release 7.6 with SELinux enabled. But sealert does not show any errors related to this.

Comment: Does your usecase mandates so many arguments `--disable-extensions`, etc?

Comment: The pages take a long time to load. So minimizing the work, to improve performance.

Comment: my wild guess, so many `arguments` are clogging up the browser initialization.

Comment: If I execute the same script as a normal user or root, it is working. So I am not sure that is the case.

Comment: But ideally you should execute your tests as a **non-root** user and the reson I am unable to point you to a canonical target discussion.

Comment: I tried removing --disable-extensions and a few more options and got the same error. If I run the test using my id (jayadevan), it works. If I run it using root, it works. But if I run using apache, it does not work.

Comment: Are you using `openshift`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205946/discussion-between-jayadevan-and-debanjanb).

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No. Switched to chrome driver.